# What is this evergreen white-flowered Bush growing in the shade?

Tags: identification, broad-leaved-evergreens

[image]
It has little white flowers in June, doesn't lose leaves in winter, grows in shade, leggy, hardy in zone 6A.

Comment: Is the plant scented?

Comment: Not noticeably scented.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I've been able to get is Ilex verticillata, Winterberry.  This is a difficult one to find on the internet[image: Winterberry pic]  My goodness; evergreen shrub, ovate/obovate, entire edges, alternate leaves, white 6 petaled flower.  Other sites say this leaf is serrated?  I can only spend so much time doing this, so OCD!!  So this is not a hard and fast ID at all.

http://www.delawarewildflowers.org/images/ilex_verticillata.jpg

Comment: Hey, no problemo.  What do you think it is?  I got going and gee, 3 hours later...ugh!!

Comment: Yeah, like I am such a snob expert...shame